# Why my Drag in jquery doesn't work?

Tags: jquery

I made some sample of jQuery Dragging

http://jsbin.com/ehuke4/6/edit

Its all ok when i drag to the right

But when I drag to the left it stops

I think its becuase im out of the item.

How can i fix it ?

p.s :  you can save it in the editor.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**UPDATE:** [Updated your JSBin](http://jsbin.com/ehuke4/8/edit) with quite a few changes to get it to work. You need to detect mouseup, mousedown and mousemove events on the 'document' and use a second boolean to check if the box is being held. Hope this helps.

Also, I love what Threedubmedia has done with drag and drop interactivity. [Go here](http://threedubmedia.com/code/event/drag/demo/basic) and check out their basic example if you want. I use their libraries in some of my projects. Where I think their basic example will be particularly useful for you is: when I click and drag your box its position does not drag relative to where you grabbed it. Their example would help to correct this.

Answer (score 0):

[My version](http://jsbin.com/ehuke4/10).

Also bound some of those events to the document, but instead of using the boolean, I set and unset the handlers when the mouse is down or up, respectively. This way the mousemove event isn't called when you're not actually dragging, which should be better for performance.